# Chat multi threads

Tags: java, jsf, thread, multithreading, chat

Galera estou desenvolvendo um chat bot, a questão com a resposta que o bot dá está tudo certo, o meu problema é quando mais de uma pessoa entra em contato com o chat, ele está tratando como se ambos fosse um só, eu acredito que o problema está na forma que eu estou tratando as requisições que o usuário faz.

essa é a minha managedBeam

```
    public String submit(){
        System.out.println("====submit======");

        getInteracoes().add(new InteracaoChat(1, userInput,Util.dataFormatada()));
        //realiza interaçao com o chat
        setBotOutput(new RealizaPerguntBot().realizaPergunta(userInput));

        return "";
    }


public class RealizaPerguntBot {
    /**
     * metodo responsavel por criar conexao com o watson e devolver uma resposta adequada para a pergunta realizada
     * 
     * @param pergunta
     * @return resposta
     */

    /**
     * O contexto é onde a conversa está no momento da interação, o contexto inicia como nulo pois é o inicio da conversa, a medida que vai 
     * encaminhando a conversa o contexto irá recebendo um novo valor, caso assumir nulo novamente a conversa irá voltar ao inicio
     */
    static Map<String, Object> context =  null;

    public String realizaPergunta(String pergunta){
//      
        /**
         * Service é uma classe nativa do watson, recebe a data (versão) do conversation
         */
        ConversationService service = new ConversationService(ConstantesWatson.DATE_VERSION_CONVERSATION);

        /*
         * configura o servico, recebe o usuario e a senha 
         * */
        service.setUsernameAndPassword(ConstantesWatson.USER_NAME_CONVERSATION, ConstantesWatson.PASSWORD_CONVERSATION);

        /**
         * newMesage é ai que será feito a interação do usuário com o bot, é passado a pergunta(interação) que o usuário fez ao bot, é passado o contexto
         * para que o bot saiba onde a conversa parou
         */
        MessageRequest newMessage = new MessageRequest.Builder().inputText(pergunta).context(context).build();



        String workspaceId = ConstantesWatson.WORKSPACE_ID_CONVERSATION;
        /**
         * Response recebe a resposta do bot com base na pergunta feita, é necessário passar o worksapeceid e a pergunta realizada pelo usuario
         */
        MessageResponse response = service.message(workspaceId, newMessage).execute();
        //recebe o novo valor do contexto.
        context = response.getContext();



        return new TrataRespostaJson().trataResponstaJson(response.toString());
    }
```

Gostaria de saber de vocês como eu faria para solucionar esse problema, se a implementação de threads resolveria o problema, caso seja isso, me indique uma forma mais adequada para fazer.

Grato